# Google Cloud Search Query via Node.js Error: This project doesn't have Cloud Search's Query API Enabled

Tags: google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-search

I am working on Google Cloud Search API to search documents stored in Google Drive. I have Google Workspace account and few documents stored in Google Drive. I am able to search using Google Cloud search console but facing issue using below node.js code for searching using API.

Issue: I am able to generate the access token but get below error for search query:

> Error: This project doesn't have Cloud Search's Query API Enabled,
> and/or the Cloud Search Platform license has not been assigned to the
> user account calling the Query API

```
var {google} = require("googleapis");

var serviceAccount  = require('C:/nodejstest/key/serviceAccountKey.json');

// Specify the required scope.
var scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_search",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_search.query"
  ];

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: serviceAccount.client_email,
  key: serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes: scopes,
  subject: 'sample@example.com'
});

// Use the JWT client to generate an access token.
jwtClient.authorize(function(error, tokens) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error making request to generate access token:", error);
    } else if (tokens.access_token === null) {
      console.log("Provided service account does not have permission to generate access tokens");
    } else {
      var accessToken = tokens.access_token;
      console.log('accessToken= ' + accessToken)
      // Include the access token in the Authorization header.
    }
  });


const service = google.cloudsearch({version: 'v1'});
service.query.search({
    auth: jwtClient,
    requestBody: {
      requestOptions: {
        searchApplicationId: 'searchapplications/default',
        debugOptions:{enableDebugging: true}
      },
      query: 'My query'
    }
  }).then((res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify({results:res.results.length}));
  console.log(JSON.stringify({resultsInfo:res.results[0]}));
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error('Unexpected error with cloud search API.');
  console.error(err.toString());
});
```

In above code I am passing workspace admins email id as subject.

I followed steps mentioned at below link

- [Configure access to the Google Cloud Search REST API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/project-setup)
- [Perform Google Workspace domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the google console then select the your project.

Then search for Cloud Search API then enable it.

[image: From gcp console]

Also make sure that your service account have access on Cloud Search Indexing API